# Can I merge /home for 10.10 and 10.04

Tags: 10.10, 10.04

or what can go wrong regarding config files?

I have an old installation of 10.10 and for testing purposes want 10.04 in parallel, I'd like to use my 10.10 gnome&al configuration there without crashing something

Comment: Are you merging them from different computers? Are you contemplating whether to upgrade or re-install? Please explain a bit of the circumstances, maybe there's a better solution.

Comment: @Stefano I have an old installation of 10.10 and for testing purposes want 10.04 in parallel, I'd like to use my 10.10 gnome&al configuration there without crashing something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same home folder shared between 10.04 and 10.10. Nothing serious went wrong.
Rhythmbox alone gives me a alert that the music database is not compatible, but it isn't a problem for me. Everything else works really cool and I don't face any problems because of home folder being shared.

Answer (score 3):

Chances are nothing will go wrong but I would suggest you use separate profiles to avoid problems, especially if you have other software on either installation.

The GNOME configuration for the most part shouldn't cause too much trouble, though you might encounter a few gconf related issues.